# How to handle transient failure in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I would like to ask some issues. I have got some of entity exceptions.

I am using Entity Framework 6.2.0 in my C# Windows app and SQL Server 2017. My app is running with 8 client PCs and server.

I really don't know how to that exception is occur. Is it related to connection timeout? How to fix that?

I get this exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
>
> If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition.
>   See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 58) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Some code:

```
try
{
    using (DataCtx.RTAD_BusinessLicenseEntities ctx = new DataCtx.RTAD_BusinessLicenseEntities())
    {
        err = "if(rv.TransactionStatus)=>InsertMode: " + this.txtSearchNRC.Text + ", " + this.TransactionID + ", " + paraChalenNumber.Value.ToString();
        ctx.SP_Vehicle_ApproveForExtendOperatorLicense(Helper.convertToAnscii(this.txtSearchNRC.Text), this.TransactionID, paraChalenNumber, true, true, "Approved");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Helper.WriteErrorLog("User Input => " + err + "\n\n" + ex.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "btnApply_Click_Err", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a timeout (though I can't promise you it's not the case). Unfortunately, without any code that cause this exception, it's hard to tell. How are you injecting your services / repository ? Using the Dependency Injection from ASP.NET ? Do you register services as transient, scoped, or singleton ?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete. I am using with store procedure. I don't use asp.net. My server is local. I have not register services as transient and so on. How to register? I have edit to my post and added some of code. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For EF **Core**, use [`EnableRetryOnFailure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsbuilder.enableretryonfailure):

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        myConnectionString,
        sqlOptionsBuilder => sqlOptionsBuilder.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
```

To quote the documentation:

> Default values of 6 for the maximum retry count and 30 seconds for the maximum default delay are used.

You can override these defaults by using overloads of that method.

---

If you need to customise how EF Core attempts to perform retries over and above what `EnableRetryOnFailure` provides, you can inherit the [`SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverretryingexecutionstrategy) class and
override its various methods like `Execute` and `Retry`. To register it, you'd use:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        myConnectionString,
        sqlOptionsBuilder =>
            sqlOptionsBuilder.ExecutionStrategy(dependencies =>
                new MySpecialSqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy(dependencies))));
```

[Further reference.](https://makolyte.com/how-to-do-retries-in-ef-core/)

Answer (score 1):

> In the cloud environment you'll find that failed and dropped database
>   connections happen periodically. That's partly because you're going
>   through more load balancers compared to the on-premises environment
>   where your web server and database server have a direct physical
>   connection. Also, sometimes when you're dependent on a multi-tenant
>   service you'll see calls to the service get slower or time out because
>   someone else who uses the service is hitting it heavily. In other
>   cases you might be the user who is hitting the service too frequently,
>   and the service deliberately throttles you – denies connections – in
>   order to prevent you from adversely affecting other tenants of the
>   service.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling

Here's how to fix using EF 6:

```
// EF follows a Code based Configuration model and will look for a class that
// derives from DbConfiguration for executing any Connection Resiliency strategies
public class EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EFConfiguration()
    {
        AddExecutionStrategy(() => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }
}
```